# Get caret position in input to capitalize words on keyup while being able to edit the content

Tags: jquery, caret, capitalization, getcaretpos

I decided to open a new question because I was trying to capitalize the first letter of words with 4 or more letters and with the exception of a few key words and I have this working code for that: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2tFx/11/

```
$.fn.capitalize = function () {
 var wordsToIgnore = ["to", "and", "the", "it", "or", "that", "this"],
    minLength = 3;

  function getWords(str) {
    return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
  }
  this.each(function () {
    var words = getWords(this.value);
    $.each(words, function (i, word) {
      // only continue if word is not in ignore list
      if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word).toLowerCase()) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
        words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
      }
    });
    this.value = words.join("");
  });
};

$('.title').on('keyup', function () {
  $(this).capitalize();
}).capitalize();
```

But I have a problem while running the function on **"keyup"**. **I can't edit something in the middle of the input** without getting the cursor at the end of the input. And I also **can't "select all"**.

I know there are solutions to get the caret position and take care of things like this, but I really don't know how to integrate them to my code.

Any idea on how could I do this?

Comment: You want to capitalize all of the words or just the first one?

Comment: @BlakePlumb I need to capitalize all the words. The code with "blur" instead of "keyup" is working just as I need. The problem is that I want to capitalize the words "live" while typing, but with "keyup" I can't edit in the middle of the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this, using two functions, from here: http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea

See working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2tFx/14/

```
$.fn.capitalize = function (e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey) return false;
  var wordsToIgnore = ["to", "and", "the", "it", "or", "that", "this"],
    minLength = 3;

  function getWords(str) {
    return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
  }
  this.each(function () {
    var words = getWords(this.value);
    $.each(words, function (i, word) {
      // only continue if word is not in ignore list
      if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word).toLowerCase()) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
        words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
      }
    });
    var pos = getCaretPosition(this);
    this.value = words.join("");
    setCaretPosition(this, pos);
  });
};

$('.title').on('keyup', function (e) {
  var e = window.event || evt;
  if( e.keyCode == 17 || e.which == 17) return false;
  $(this).capitalize(e);
}).capitalize();


function getCaretPosition (ctrl) {
    var CaretPos = 0;   // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
    ctrl.focus ();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange ();
        Sel.moveStart ('character', -ctrl.value.length);
        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
    return (CaretPos);
}
function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos){
    if(ctrl.setSelectionRange)
    {
        ctrl.focus();
        ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
    }
    else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
        var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

You should incorporate this two functions in your capitalize function scope

Comment: Thank you *very much*. It just works. One question, do you know if there's some workaround to be able to "select all" with ctrl+a with this code? I can select all by double clicking on the input though...

Comment: Updated answer with jsfiddle to take into account ctrl+A or any other combo with ctrl hot key